# Flutter list query

Tags: flutter

Im trying to check a list inside list and then show it as ViewList

for example

const Sport = [
  {
    "Name": "James",
    "SportTaq": ["Soccer", "American football"],
  },
];

and then check list witch include loud Soccer

print(Sport.where((item) => item["SportTaq"].contains("Soccer")));

but it did not work can you help me with it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
void main() {
  const Sport = [
    {
      "Name": "James",
      "SportTaq": ["Soccer", "American football"],
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "SportTaq": ["American football","basketball"],
    },
  ];

  print(Sport.where((item) {
   List sports = item["SportTaq"];
   return sports.contains("Soccer");
  }).toList());
}
```

Comment: Hello @MouhammadAlhajjiTheRiver if it works can you vote and accept as an answer clicking on the checkbox?